# Correct way to pass state from one component to another

Tags: reactjs

I am getting myself a bit confused with React.

I have a home 'page' which I am breaking up into components. So, I have a hero component which at the moment just has a title which is pulled from mongodb.

So, on the home page I have:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
// the axios http request to the server
import { getHero } from "../services/heroService";

//state
class Home extends Component {
  state = {
    title: "",
  };

  async componentDidMount() {
    const response = await getHero();
    this.setState({ title: response.data.title });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <Hero title={this.state.title} />
    );
  }
}
export default Home;
```

Then my hero component:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Container } from "react-bootstrap";

class Hero extends Component {
  render() {
    const { title } = this.props;
    return (
      <section className="section-hero d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center mb-5">
        <Container className="text-center text-white">
          <h1>{title}</h1>
        </Container>
      </section>
    );
  }
}
export default Hero;
```

I just wanted to know if this was the correct way to pass the data from the state to another component. It seems to work but that does't mean it's right.

Comment: By the way, questions like this are a better fit at [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), another website of the Stack Exchange!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, that is the right way.

Basically when passing data between components, you can have several cases, here are the canonical *"React-way"* of doing:

- `<A>` is the parent of `<B>`, data flows from `<A>` to `<B>` (your case): data is stored in `A.state`, and is passed through props: `<B data={this.state.data}>`
- `<A>` is the parent of `<B>`, data flows from `<B>` to `<A>`: data is stored in `A.state`, and a listener is passed through props: `<B onDataChange={newData => this.updateData(newData)}>`
- `<A>` and `<B>` are close siblings and share data: data is stored in the closest common ancestor, listeners are passed through props (aka [lifting the state up](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html))
- `<A>` and `<B>` are independent and share data: use a state container like [Redux](https://redux.js.org/basics/usage-with-react)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is right way to pass data from a parent /  container components to child components, in case you are using redux, you can only add the props of parent/container component to store and child /view component can only have responsibility to show /display the data.