# Fetching data in other components with react hook

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

Im new to react hooks and are experimenting a bit. I can display my values that are generated in Provider.js in App.js through Comptest.js. My problem is that the structure of my project with css etc makes it inconvenient to have a structure in the App.js like this:

```
<Provider>
    <Comptest />
</Provider>
```

is it possible to fetch the data without displaying the components in that way in the app? just passing it between the components.

Here is a compact version of my application:

**App.js**

```
import React, { useContext } from "react";
import Provider from "./Provider";
import Comptest from "./Comptest";
import DataContext from "./Context";

function App() {

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h2>My array!</h2>
      <Provider>
        <Comptest />
      </Provider>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

**Provider.js**

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import DataContext from "./Context";

const Provider = props => {
  const data = ["item1", "item2"];

  return (
    <DataContext.Provider value={data}>{props.children}</DataContext.Provider>
  );
};

export default Provider;
```

**Comptest.js**

```
import React from "react";
import DataContext from "./Context";

const Comptest = () => {
  const content = React.useContext(DataContext);

  console.log(content);

  return <div>{(content)}</div>;
};

export default Comptest;
```

**Context.js**

```
import React from "react";

const DataContext = React.createContext([]);

export default DataContext;
```

Comment: React cheatsheet for passing data between components: (1) components are parent/child: use props (2) components are siblings: lift the state up (3) components are unrelated: use state container. More details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56824040/8186898)

Comment: Yes. But i am using the new hooks and usecontext not classbased structure

Comment: Same. Wether you syntactically use hooks or classes, React component still have states and props and the way you pass data thanks to them is similar

Comment: Ok. Im pretty new to react and have tried to pass a value from the Provider.js to the sibling Comptest.js but cannot get it right except for the solution above but there placing Comptest inside the Provider messes up my css and the structure of the page. A working example based on mine, using hooks but lifting the state up would be very much apreciated!

Comment: What is the final structure you want to accomplish? Which component should fetch the data?